# Referencing global variables / external libraries from TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sharepoint

I am in the process of converting standard JavaScript files into TypeScript for client-side deployments in SharePoint. SharePoint has global variables and libraries we leverage without having to explicitly load them in our custom scripts. One being a global object named_spPageContextInfo. In my TS file, obviously the compiler doesn't know anything about this object, so I need to know how best to handle such situations. I'm also going to want automated testing as well, so the solution needs to handle this somehow. Mock object data?

I've gotten it to work so far by:

```
const _spPageContextInfo = window['_spPageContextInfo'];
```

Same with jQuery since jQuery is already available in my SharePoint farm:

```
const $ = window['$'];
```

Is there a better way to handle these situations where at compile time, I need to tell the compiler, don't worry, when we're deployed those objects will be available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ambient declaration to variable

`declare const $: any;`

allows compiler considers `$` available to access globally.